# Graphic content label

Tags: labels, wording, video

I'm working on a project in which we are labeling content to inform, **not** warn, the user (editors) that videos contain nudity, death, violence or adult language.

We are **not** trying to discourage people from seeing these videos and we are **not** looking to have the user agree to continue seeing them, we only want to make sure the videos are properly labeled.

I was using "**graphic content labels**" as the label, but wanted to know if there is more correct terminology for this label. Is there a more user-friendly or industry-standard way to say this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to distinguish between the forms of content?

Comment: Do you mean if labeling the content is necessary? If I understood that correctly, yes, it is a requirement.

Comment: Do you have to distinguish between nudity, violence, sex, etc. or just show a category which includes the possibility of all of them?

Comment: Yes, we have to.

Comment: @Ana after your comment I realized that I had severely misinterpreted the context of the question. So I removed my post.

Comment: No problem at all. Initially, I had the same reaction. I thought it cheapened our content.

Answer (score 5):

Here are the icons that the Dutch 'Kijkwijzer' (viewer guide) uses:

[image]

(There's also PEGI, an equivalent for computer games)

These are pretty clean indicators of what the content contains without any judgmental indicators like danger colors or exclamation points. I don't think you're allowed to use these icons, but you can take some inspiration from them.

**Edit**: descriptions from left to right: violence, sex, general scary things, drug references, discrimination, coarse language.

Comment: Thanks! We were trying to come up wit icons, but the biggest problem we faced is the higher level label. I think "viewer guide" might help.

Comment: +1 Answer would be even more helpful if you added the description for each icon. They are not all self-explanatory.

Comment: @ Marjan good point, I've added them.

Comment: I actually am going to use only text. It is a profesional tool and I need to keep the tone super neutral.

Answer (score 4):

The following trademarked [PEGI descriptors](http://www.pegi.info/en/index/id/33/) (as Peter mentions) are shown below and used for videogaming. These are Europe wide classifications but in the UK replaced the BBFC ratings when the PEGI system was given a [government approval](http://www.thetechherald.com/articles/BBFC-dropped-as-PEGI-videogame-ratings-given-government-nod).

Note that here PEGI have used the term *descriptors* as opposed to *warnings* or anything that is attempting to be positive or negative. They are used in conjunction with the age ratings.

So perhaps in terms of labeling, you could simply use the term **Content descriptors**

[image]

Comment: Content descriptor is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Reddit uses a **tag labeled "NSFW"** (not safe for work).

The thumbnail is also blocked, like this:

[image]

Comment: I had the same discussion with my husband, BUT it is very safe for work, actually it is part of their work, so I can't use it. <3 reddit.